# postgres: unnesting an array and counting totals

Tags: postgresql

I have data that looks like this:

```
winning_pid  losing_pid  pair  wins
          1           2   1,2     7
          2           1   1,2     3
          3           4   3,4     2
```

And I want a result that looks like this:

```
pid  opp_pid  total  wins  losses
  1        2     10     7      3
  2        1     10     3      7
  3        4      2     2      0
  4        3      2     0      2
```

It's basically: matchup totals per `pid` value and an opponent `pid` value, with a total between them and a # of wins and losses. As you can see, you have situations where a `losing_pid` value never shows in the `winning_pid` column as that `pid` value has no wins, but these need to be in the totals table.

Is there a quick solution using `UNNEST()` on pair? I can't do something like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (pair) UNNEST(pair) as pid, COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE pid = winning_pid ) AS wins` because it doesn't recognize `pid` in the `FILTER` clause.

I'm also thinking `UNNEST()` isn't what I want as I want a results table that has both `pid` values, versus just the one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union for switched results:

```
select
    pid, 
    opp_pid, 
    sum(wins + loses) total,
    sum(wins) wins, 
    sum(loses) loses
from (
    select winning_pid pid, losing_pid opp_pid, wins, 0 loses
    from example
    union
    select losing_pid, winning_pid, 0, wins
    from example
) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

Test it in [rextester](http://rextester.com/TTVK59017).